# In a c++ macro how to concatenate -> and function name

Tags: c++, macros

```
#define FUNC_MACRO(FuncName)  \
  do {                        \
    stub-> ## FuncName ## (   \
      arg1, arg2);            \
  } while(0)

  FUNC_MACRO(Func1);
```

Gives following error,

**error: pasting "->" and "Func1" does not give a valid preprocessing token**

I have tried many combinations, none of then worked.

```
stub->##FuncName##(

stub-> ## FuncName(

stub->##FuncName(

stub ## -> ## FuncName ## (

stub##->##FuncName(

stub##->##FuncName##(
```

Comment: Why are you fighting with token pasting syntax ?? What's wrong with [just doing this](https://godbolt.org/z/1b7dhzdfo) ?? Did you try just using `stub->FuncName(` ??

Comment: Token pasting is when a single token needs to be constructed from a macro argument and other stuff.  But `stub`, `->`, `FuncName`, `(` need to be separate tokens anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`##` is meant to concatentate 2 preprocessor tokens into a new token. That is NOT what you need in this situation. Simple token replacement will suffice.

So, you don't need to use `##` at all. Just use `stub->FuncName`, and the preprocessor will replace `FuncName` with the caller's input value, as you are expecting (ie, `FUNC_MACRO(Func1)` will produce `stub->Func1`).

However, you do need to fix the parameters that you are passing to `stub->FuncName`, as you can't *declare* parameters inside a function call.  Did you mean to do something more like this?

```
#define FUNC_MACRO(FuncName, arg1, arg2) \
  do { \
    stub->FuncName(arg1, arg2); \
  } while(0)
```

```
SomeType value1, value2;
FUNC_MACRO(Func1, value1, value2);
```